# how to get date from database to html datepicker

Tags: php, mysql, html, codeigniter, datepicker

How can I get value of date from database to html datepicker?? 
following is my html code.

```
<input type="date" class="m-wrap" value=<?php $result[0]->startdate?> name="date" <?php if(!$is_master_admin){ ?> min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); }?>" />
```

in database datatype of datefield is "date".

Simply i would like to retrieve date from mysql to html5 datepicker

Comment: Not clear .where the issue is ?

Comment: @MahmoodRehman In database i have one date field and its datatype is date.
while i am inserting date into this field using post method it will added successfully,
but when i want to edit form at that time i want that date from databasse in my datepicker.

issue is that how to retrieve date in datepicker from database

Comment: Means when you load edit form , your date picker loaded with added date automatically ? right

Comment: @MahmoodRehman Yes sir exactly you are right

Comment: you should echo your data in your text box value attribute `<?php echo $result[0]->startdate?>`

Comment: @kumar_v
nope your wrong,
i got my ans ..
i am posting my ans here

Comment: @Ritesh however you missed echo in your question.

Comment: firstof all that is not textbox and if I do echo there then also it will not print date from databse to datepicker.
i have to convert it 
that is the logic behind this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 <input type="date" class="m-wrap" value="<?php echo strftime('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime($result[0]->startdate)); ?>" name="date" />
```