# how to display date from database to input type=date in php

Tags: php, mysql, date

i have a field from my database which is start/end date sample fields is

**sample field**

```
start_date   |   end_date
2017-04-19   |   2017-04-23
```

what i want to do is to display this data to my:

```
<input type="date" name= "start_date" value="<?php echo $value['start_date']?>">
```

but what happen is it doesn't display anything... i tried to use

```
<input type="date" name= "start_date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($value["start_date"]))?>">
```

but it displays a different date which is not from my database.. any suggestion to display the date data from my db to the input type="date" ??

Comment: [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019473/how-to-get-date-from-database-to-html-datepicker) Hope it works for your case

Comment: woah nice...  its working now...thanks for this... but im a bit confuse with the two between date('Y-m-d') and strftime('%Y-%m-%d') .. but thanks alot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get date from database to html datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019473/how-to-get-date-from-database-to-html-datepicker)

Answer (score 3):

`strtotime` is use to format a local **time/date** according to **locale   settings**
Try like this:-

```
<input type="date" class="m-wrap" value="<?php echo strftime('%Y-%m-%d',
  strtotime($value['start_date'])); ?>" name="date" />
```

It will work for you .TO check about `strtotime`  look [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

Comment: How to check if date is not set in database? In some records, I have `NULL` values

Comment: Hi @AjinkyaRathod, In this situation, you can check the time and if not present then you can set the current date (i.e `echo date("Y-m-d")`) .